# How to login user with passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I've been trying to setup passport with my express application. However when trying to use passport.authenticate , I recieve a 401 unauththorized on postman. I alsoing tried it on the browser, but I'm getting a similar error.

Heres my setup

userModel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;



const userModel = new Schema({
    username:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
    password:{type:String,required:true},
    bio:{type:String},
     jobs:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Job'}]

})
userModel.plugin(require('passport-local-mongoose'));

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userModel);
```

passport.config.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const passport = require('passport');
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('./Models/userModel.js');

passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

index.js

```
const userModel = require('./Models/userModel');
const jobModel = require('./Models/jobModel');

const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
 passport.use(new LocalStrategy(userModel.authenticate()));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: "secretkey", resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));

require("./passport.config");
app.use(passport.initialize()); 
app.use(passport.session()); 



mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,{useNewUrlParser:true},() => {
    console.log('mongodb connected')
})




app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
  
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.send(req.user);
 });
```

Comment: `trying to use passport.authenticate`, try what?

Comment: in my app.post('/login')

Answer (score 0):

You have set the passport.use 2 times with different mongoose schema.
passport.config have this line:

```
passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
```

index.js have this:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(userModel.authenticate()));
```

decide which one you want to use.

Also you did not set the passport-local strategy right.
The strategy requires a verify callback, which accepts credentials(username and password) and calls done on finish providing user.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

you can also try to change this:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(userModel.authenticate()));
```

to

```
passport.use(userModel.authenticate());
```

source: [passport docs](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/)

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm also using passport-mongoose which abstracts some of passports complexity. I removed one of the passport..use but I still recieve unathenticated.